# Metricbeat Beat failed to connect es (xpack enabled)

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat, xpack

**Helm Version:**   "v3.1.1"

**`helm get release` output**

helm status metricbeat
NAME: metricbeat
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Apr 30 10:05:32 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1

**Describe the bug:** Unable to connect to elasticsearch, deployed configmap does not contain username: and password input.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Enable xpack in elasticsearch
2. run - *helm install metricbeat elastic/metricbeat --set imageTag=7.6.2 --values metrics.yaml*

**metrics.yaml**

```
daemonset:
  extraEnvs:
    - name: 'ES_USERNAME'
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: elastic-credentials
          key: username
    - name: 'ES_PASSWORD'
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: elastic-credentials
          key: password
  # Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/metricbeat
  # such as metricbeat.yml for daemonset
  metricbeatConfig:
    metricbeat.yml: |
      metricbeat.modules:
      - module: kubernetes
        metricsets:
          - container
          - node
          - pod
          - system
          - volume
        period: 10s
        host: "${NODE_NAME}"
        hosts: ["${NODE_NAME}:10250"]
        # bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        # ssl.verification_mode: "none"
        # If using Red Hat OpenShift remove ssl.verification_mode entry and
        # uncomment these settings:
        #ssl.certificate_authorities:
          #- /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-ca.crt
        processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
      - module: kubernetes
        enabled: true
        metricsets:
          - event
      - module: system
        period: 10s
        metricsets:
          - cpu
          - load
          - memory
          - network
          - process
          - process_summary
        processes: ['.*']
        process.include_top_n:
          by_cpu: 5
          by_memory: 5
      - module: system
        period: 1m
        metricsets:
          - filesystem
          - fsstat
        processors:
        - drop_event.when.regexp:
            system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib)($|/)'
      output.elasticsearch:
        username: '${ES_USERNAME}'
        password: '${ES_PASSWORD}'
        hosts: ["elasticsearch-master:9200"]


deployment:
  extraEnvs:
    - name: 'ES_USERNAME'
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: elastic-credentials
          key: username
    - name: ES_PASSWORD'
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: elastic-credentials
          key: password
  # Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/metricbeat
  # such as metricbeat.yml for deployment
  metricbeatConfig:
    metricbeat.yml: |
      metricbeat.modules:
      - module: kubernetes
        enabled: true
        metricsets:
          - state_node
          - state_deployment
          - state_replicaset
          - state_pod
          - state_container
        period: 10s
        hosts: ["${KUBE_STATE_METRICS_HOSTS}"]
      output.elasticsearch:
        username: '${ES_USERNAME}'
        password: '${ES_PASSWORD}'
        hosts: ["elasticsearch-master:9200"]
```

***metricbeat.yml  after deployment does not contain username and password inputs:***

```
 metricbeat.modules:
    - module: kubernetes
      metricsets:
        - container
        - node
        - pod
        - system
        - volume
      period: 10s
      host: "${NODE_NAME}"
      hosts: ["${NODE_NAME}:10255"]
      processors:
      - add_kubernetes_metadata:
          in_cluster: true
    - module: kubernetes
      enabled: true
      metricsets:
        - event
    - module: system
      period: 10s
      metricsets:
        - cpu
        - load
        - memory
        - network
        - process
        - process_summary
      processes: ['.*']
      process.include_top_n:
        by_cpu: 5
        by_memory: 5
    - module: system
      period: 1m
      metricsets:
        - filesystem
        - fsstat
      processors:
      - drop_event.when.regexp:
          system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib)($|/)'
    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:elasticsearch-master:9200}'
```

**Expected behavior:** should connect to es using username and password without an issue.

**Provide logs and/or server output (if relevant):**

```
   pipeline/output.go:100 Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://elasticsearch-master:9200)): 401 Unauthorized: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}
```

**Any additional context:**

I am able to connect elastic search using same credentials and it works fine with Kibana login as well.

Comment: From the [readme](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts): "Note that we don't support Helm 3 version." Have you tried this with Helm version 2? https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/401 has some more details on the upgrade plan and how you might be able to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of [Elastic Helm charts](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts).

Due to a recent refactoring, the values `daemonset.xxx` and `deployment.xxx` documented on Git repository master branch aren't compatible with the current released chart version.

If you want to install the current released version ([7.6.2](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/releases/tag/7.6.2)), you can find the values to use on the [README from 7.6.2 release](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/7.6.2/metricbeat/README.md#configuration).

If you want to deploy the next version which should be released soon and will use `daemonset.xxx` and `deployment.xxx` values, you can clone the repo and use the [installation instructions from `7.7` branch](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/7.7/metricbeat/README.md#using-the-77-branch).

PS: As mentioned in comment, please note that Elastic charts don't support Helm v3 yet, we still advise using Helm v2.